# Run C executable(tests) in Jmeter

Tags: c, jmeter, performance-testing

I am a newbie to Jmeter testing. I am required to run a bunch of C/C++ executables that performance test a C API using JMeter. Is it possible to create a .jmx script that talks to the C/C++ performance test code? If possible how can I do it? There is no web interface to the tests that I need to run.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helps. I was able to work on it just now hence the delayed response.  Tried a basic shell script and a couple Linux commands using the OS Process sampler.Should work for my C executables too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this sampler:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler

It can run any executable.

Another option is to use JNI or JNA to wrap C/C++ into a Java class and use Java Request sampler:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request